# Can't make array from numbers in while cycle

Tags: perl

I'm having a problem with my array. I'm trying to make new array's from `@mas3` , The problem is with `@mas6` my program doesn't add any numbers that is below 10 to the array. But as you can see there is few numbers in the array `@mas3` that are lower than 10.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$eilute1 = "Sveiki man yra 10 metu as buvau gimtadienyje pries 2 metus";
$eilute2 = "Sveiki man sueis 15 metu o kazkada buvo tik 5";

print "$eilute1";
print "$eilute2";
print "\n";
@mas1=split(" ",$eilute1);
@mas2=split(" ",$eilute2);
print "Pirmas masyvas\n@mas1\nAntras masyvas\n@mas2\n";
print "\n";
print "Pirmas naujas masyvas\n";
my @mas3=(@mas1,@mas2);
print "@mas3\n";
my $i=0;
my $x=scalar(@mas3);
while($i < $x){

my $reiksme=@mas3[$i];

if(length($reiksme) > 4) { my @mas4=push(@mas4,$reiksme); }
elsif(length($reiksme) <= 4) { my @mas5=push(@mas5,$reiksme); }
elsif($reiksme < 10) { my @mas6=push(@mas6,$reiksme); }
else { print " ## Error ##\n" } ;
$i++;
}
print "\n";
print "@mas4\n";
print "@mas5\n";
print "@mas6\n";
```

Comment: `use strict; use warnings`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tidied your program a little so that I can see properly where the blocks start and end. I've also added `use strict` and `use warnings`, which are essential, as someone commented.

As Zbynek wrote, every word is either longer than four characters or four characters and shorter so one of the first two conditions will always succeed and, the third condition is never tested.

The easiest way to test whether a string contains a number is using a regular expression. I've used `$reiksme =~ /\d/ and length $reiksme == 1` where the regular expression `/\d/` tests whether the string contains a digit, and if it's only one character long then it must be 0 to 9. I've also moved the test to the beginning so that it isn't overridden by the other two tests

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $eilute1 = "Sveiki man yra 10 metu as buvau gimtadienyje pries 2 metus";
my $eilute2 = "Sveiki man sueis 15 metu o kazkada buvo tik 5";

print "$eilute1\n";
print "$eilute2\n";
print "\n";

my @mas1 = split ' ', $eilute1;
my @mas2 = split ' ', $eilute2;

print "Pirmas masyvas\n@mas1\nAntras masyvas\n@mas2\n";
print "\n";
print "Pirmas naujas masyvas\n";

my @mas3 = ( @mas1, @mas2 );
print "@mas3\n";

my (@mas4, @mas5, @mas6);

for my $reiksme ( @mas3 ) {

    if ( $reiksme =~ /\d/ and length $reiksme == 1   ) {
        push @mas6, $reiksme;
    }
    elsif ( length($reiksme) > 4 ) {
        push @mas4, $reiksme;
    }
    elsif ( length($reiksme) <= 4 ) {
        push @mas5, $reiksme;
    }
    else {
        print " ## Error ##\n";
    }
}

print "\n";

print "4 - @mas4\n\n";
print "5 - @mas5\n\n";
print "6 - @mas6\n\n";
```

#### output

```
Sveiki man yra 10 metu as buvau gimtadienyje pries 2 metus
Sveiki man sueis 15 metu o kazkada buvo tik 5

Pirmas masyvas
Sveiki man yra 10 metu as buvau gimtadienyje pries 2 metus
Antras masyvas
Sveiki man sueis 15 metu o kazkada buvo tik 5

Pirmas naujas masyvas
Sveiki man yra 10 metu as buvau gimtadienyje pries 2 metus Sveiki man sueis 15 metu o kazkada buvo tik 5

4 - Sveiki buvau gimtadienyje pries metus Sveiki sueis kazkada

5 - man yra 10 metu as man 15 metu o buvo tik

6 - 2 5
```

Comment: Genius! thank you very much. Where I could learn more about all those `/\d/` things? :)

Comment: @TomasVilemaitis:  All of the Perl documents are installed together with Perl itself. You can run `perldoc perlre` or look at the same information [on line here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

Comment: and what `=~` means? :)

Comment: Apply this regex comparison to the thing on the left hand side. Documented in `perldoc perlop`

Comment: @TomasVilemaitis: You write `STRING =~ PATTERN` to test whether a string matches a regular expression pattern. The result is a true or a false depending on whether the string matched. In the above `$reiksme =~ /\d/` it is testing whether `$reiksme` matches the pattern `/\d/`, that is to say it contains a numerical digit (anywhere)

Comment: @sobrique: Why is your answer answer so stiff? I think our questioner is from Lithuania and may also need help with English, but you explain one difficult idea in terms of another

Comment: @sobrique: I'm sorry, do I mean stern, not stiff. I'm sorry

Comment: Because it's slightly politer than "RTFM" and explaining it in detail is a separate question entirely.

Comment: @sobrique: So you can be rude or stern, but not caring. Agh! All you people care about is your fame. I don't think I like you Mr Sobrique

Comment: A more detailed explanation of terms - requested for clarification in comments - would be better edited into the answer, as comments are ephemeral. Even if that is just a reference to the appropriate piece of documentation.

Answer (score 0):

All the items are put into `@mas4` or `@mas5` arrays as the first or second conditions are always satisfied, so any `else` block couldn't be ever reached:

```
if(length($reiksme) > 4) { my @mas4=push(@mas4,$reiksme); }
elsif(length($reiksme) <= 4) { my @mas5=push(@mas5,$reiksme); }
```

There can't be any else for them, either variable is bigger than 4 or lower or equal than 4.

Additionally, for the `$reiksme < 10` you probably miss `length()` around `$reiksme`.

Last but not least - you don't need to assign the result of push to other variable, the original one which you pass as parameter is modified.

Comment: Well if string length is more than 4 it goes to `@mas4` if it's less or equal to 4 it goes to `mas5` this part works perfectly. I didn't miss it, I want to compare only numbers.